# How to blur panel in the back like Ext.Msg.alert does

Tags: extjs

I've create new pop-up window with new Ext.Window
I don't want user to clicks outside this window.
How can I set inactive or blur the behind panel?

Comment: This question very little effort imo.

Comment: is this question answered?

Answer (score 2):

Set `modal:true`

Read the [docs](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/) .

.